# Volley jsonObjectRequest how to handle string result

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Im trying to do a POST request to a page the parameters needed for the request have to be in a json because they are in this format:

```
{
   a: 1,
   b: "ASD",
   c: ["A","B"]
}
```

which as far as i know this cant be turned to a  `Map<String, String>` object, which is needed in order to make a `StringRequest` instead of a `JsonObjectRequest`, with that being said is there any way to send a `jsonObject` as parameter and still be able to handle a string response from the server (Using volley)?

I have read these questions already:

[How to handle string response from php using android volley JsonObjectRequest [com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327913/how-to-handle-string-response-from-php-using-android-volley-jsonobjectrequest-c)

-This one didn't get a functioning answer

[How to get string response from php using android volley JsonObjectRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344562/how-to-get-string-response-from-php-using-android-volley-jsonobjectrequest)

-This one doesn't answer my question

[Volley - POST/GET parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626032/volley-post-get-parameters)

-This one has a promising answer with custom requests, but it does the opposite of what im attempting and i was unsuccessful at creating my own custom request that accepted the params i needed.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that posting something like `a[0]:"1"` and `a[1]:"2"` in the hashmap params is the same as doing `a: ["1","2"]` so im fine using StringRequest since it uses a `<String,String>` Map for parameters, that being said i ended up using this:

```
StringRequest xx = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getAjaxUrlForFunction("Login"), new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.w("RESPONSE",response);
                callback.onSucces(response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                callback.onError(error);
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> paramss = new HashMap<String, String>();
                paramss.put("funcion","login");
                paramss.put("ajax_request","controller");
                paramss.put("args[0]", name);
                paramss.put("args[1]", password);
                return paramss;
            }
        };
```